# What advice do you give to someone who's written an incomplete question below any understanding?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, deletion, new-users, advice

It happened [recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449040/) and [again today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451879/image-of-a-ball-under-a-homeomorphism#3451879) (post now deleted) that someone submitted a question with so little content that it was close to impossible to guess anything from it.

We all know that by the time the question is edited and complete, no one will have it on their radar any more, the flow of new questions being what it is. So I'm asking what advice to give in such a case:

- Do we advise the OP to delete their question and submit a new one when it's ready, with the drawback of filling storage space on SE since deleted questions are still kept in memory?
- Do we advise the OP to edit the question and make it readable, with the drawback mentioned above that no one might ever read it (well, except for users who follow the *active* tab rather than the *new* questions, but the active file has an even greater momentum and a question is not to be seen there for long to say the least)?

Comment: It depends on the tags I guess. I follow the *active* on the group-theory tag, and this is mostly manageable.

Comment: The first post you site seems to have been edited into shape, and answered, and the answer accepted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, but that's just one example I had in mind at the moment. I asked this as I was genuinely pondering on what to advise the second OP.

Comment: I'd choose the first bullet. Because in the second one, the users that might find interesting the title of the question, will click on it and then they will see the unreadable question.. it would be wasted time